# Loop to create a Variable for Total Drug Duration

Tags: r

Output of `dput(head(data,20))`

```
structure(list(Id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), time = 1:20, Event = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), Fup = c(90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 
90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L), 
    Start = 1:20, Stop = 2:21, dose = c(0, 0, 2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 
    2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 
    2.6, 2.6, 2.6)), .Names = c("Id", "time", "Event", "Fup", 
"Start", "Stop", "dose"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

I need to create a variable in my dataset called: Total Duration of Drug Use (during the entire follow-up of a given patient) and I'm creating the following loop :

```
list.id <- unique(data$Id)

nbr.subjects <- length(list.id)

tot.dur.use <- NULL

for (i in 1:nbr.subjects) {
    current.subject <- data[data$Id == list.id[i], ]
    tot.dur.use.tmp <- sum(current.subject$dose != 0)
    tot.dur.use <- c(tot.dur.use, tot.dur.use.tmp)
}
data <- cbind(data, tot.dur.use)
```

Gives the following error: **Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 70255, 498 **
Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong here?
Thanks!!!

Comment: Please provide the dataset `data` or if it is very large a sample of it. Use `dput(data)` and post the result in your question.

Comment: Do `tot.dur.use <- c(tot.dur.use, tot.dur.use.tmp)`, not `tot.dur.use.tmp <- c(...)`.

Comment: The dataset is quite large, but here is the results of head(data):                      Id time Event Fup Start Stop dose
1  1    1     0  90     1    2  0.0
2  1    2     0  90     2    3  0.0
3  1    3     0  90     3    4  2.6
4  1    4     0  90     4    5  2.6
5  1    5     0  90     5    6  2.6
6  1    6     0  90     6    7  2.6

Comment: @RuiBarradas, I tried wishing the loop:  
tot.dur.use.tmp <- sum(current.subject$dose!=0)
tot.dur.use <- c(tot.dur.use, tot.dur.use.tmp) and it's giving me this error: Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 70255, 498

Comment: Sorry, but that `sum`instruction is new, where does it fit in your code? Edit the question with that change and with the output of `head(data)`, don't put that in a comment. To post the output of `dput(head(data, 20))` is better than simply `head(...)`.

Comment: @CCurtis the results of `dput(data` is quite lengthy..

Comment: See my previous comment, it answers the issue of lengthy datasets.

Comment: @RuiBarradas just edited now.

Comment: Your code doesn't give an error. Maybe it does what you want, maybe it doesn't, it's hard to tell without an example of expected output.

Comment: @RuiBarradas, it is when I try binding it to my data set that it gives me the error. I think the problem is that in cases where the dose is 0, it doesn't know what value to give it (since I didn't define in the body of my loop) but I'm not sure how to write the code for it. Basically, I want to calculate the total duration of use (number of rows when dose is not equal to 0), so whenever the value of the dose was 0, then the count doesn't change but it remains the same as in the previous line.

Comment: `tot.dur.use <- ave(data$dose, data$Id, FUN = function(x) ifelse(x == 0, 0, sum(x != 0)))`. See if this works.

Comment: @RuiBarradas: I found out why! Thank you for your help!

Comment: @RuiBarradas: I need to re-arrange the data so that I have one line per patient (since total duration of drug use is a time-fixed covariate). So, I'm going to try to do this now and see if it works.

Comment: If you want one value per patient, try `tot.dur.use <- tapply(data$dose, data$Id, FUN = function(x) sum(x != 0))`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my `data.table` solution. This gives a running total.

```
library("data.table")
setDT(data)
data[,tot.dur := cumsum(dose),by=Id]
data
```

If you want a running count which avoids 0 then substitute the `cumsum` function with `length2<-function(x){x[x!=0]<-1:sum(x!=0);x}`. If you want to aggregate by Id and get the total non 0 dose count then.

```
data2<-data[dose!=0] #Remove rows with 0 dose
data[, lapply(.SD, length), by=Id]
```

You could also replace the length argument with a function that doesn't count 0's.

Comment: ,Thank you for your help! It worked! I wanted to ask you for suggestion on how to modify the function (the cumsum(dose) if I want to only look at the last 30 days of use.

Comment: this is what I'm trying to do: data2[,tot.cum.use.30 := cumsum((tail(data2$id,30)$dose)), by = id]
but it's not working really..

Comment: You are close but just put it into a function like this `cumsum30<-function(x){cumsum(tail(x,n=30))}`. Please select this answer as best answer so people know the question was answered.